# Configuring Coldfusion On IIS

Tags: iis, coldfusion, httphandler

I have to export a classic asp/asp.net 2.0 web site that uses also coldfusion 8, from Windows Server 2003 with IIS6 to Windows Server 2012 and IIS 8.

I got everything working except setting up coldfusion to work with IIS. 
The pages using coldfusion have .cfm as an extension.

I tried to follow this link here but that did not work

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/coldfusion/articles/iis-configuration.html

When I try to add the handlers in IIS, I see a warning saying this site is in classic mode and I need to manage managed handlers directly in the config file.

I tried to add the handlers using appcmd like this:

```
appcmd set config /section:handlers /+[name='cfmHandler',path='*.cfm',verb='*',type='c:\coldfusion8\runtime\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll',preCondition='integratedMode']
```

Then I added the Wildcard Script Map in IIS as per the link, this seems that it created and entry in the web.config of the site.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="JWildCardHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\lib\wsconfig\1\jrun_iis6_wildcard.dll" resourceType="File" requireAccess="None" preCondition="bitness32" />       
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

When I try to browse to the web site, if the wildcard handler exists in the web.config, I get error 404 on any page, even the one that does not end with .cfm

I removed the wildcard and I now get the following error:

**Handler "cfmHandler" has a bad module "ManagedPipelineHandler" in its module list**

*Most likely causes:
Managed handler is used; however, ASP.NET is not installed or is not installed completely.
There is a typographical error in the configuration for the handler module list.
During application initialization, either the application initialization feature has set skipManagedModules to true, or a rewrite rule is setting a URL that maps to a managed handler and is also setting SKIP_MANAGED_MODULES=1.*

---

I tried to run the fix that some programmers mentioned in other questions, but did not help
 c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -i

I tried to add the handler in the web.config instead of doing it through appcmd  but I got the same error.

```
<add  name="cfmHandler" path="*.cfm" verb="*" type="c:\coldfusion8\runtime\lib\wsconfig\jrun_iis6.dll" preCondition="classicMode" />
```

I have been trying to get this to work for the last 3 days without luck.

All I need get done is to make any page that ends with .cfm handled by the coldfusion server. It's obviously the web site is old .NET and probably classisMode. I could not find simple step by step instructions other than the link above which did not work for me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Questions for you first -
Have you checked if ColdFusion is running as a service?
Have you tried adding a website in IIS and then setting a root directory and placing an index.cfm there?
Do you have an Application.cfc? Have you checked if it is being called (onRequest etc function)

Comment: Yes the cold fusion service is running,  I have one site which contains both asp and cfm pages . I did not write the application, I am taking it over and I work with .net and Java, I have never used  cold fusion. I copied all the files from the old server. Where does the CFC file usually sit ? 
The error I get is whenever I request a URL for any page the has .cfm.

Comment: How about re-installing ColdFusion? Also I believe for IIS the ASP.NET,  CGI and maybe ISAPI dependencies are needed.

Comment: Firstly, have you tried using the web configurator tool that ships with ColdFusion? This is designed to set up IIS for you. The first thing I'd try is setting up a new website in IIS and running the tool - you can find it in the start menu, or if not then look for WSConfig.exe in \cfusion\runtime\bin.
Secondly, the .net mode of the site is handled in the Application Pools section of the IIS Manager. I can't think why you'd need Integrated pipeline mode for a CF site, but it wouldn't hurt. 
I'd definitely work with a new IIS site though, sounds like you've messed with the config of this one!